# Strange delay / temporary freeze when launching / using xterm

Tags: debian, xterm

When I launch `xterm`, it takes about a second to appear, unless there is another `xterm` window already opened, in which case, it is as instantaneous as it used to be.

In other words:

```
Launch xterm_1 -> slow
Launch xterm_2 -> fast
Close one of them
Launch xterm_3 -> fast
Close all xterm windows
Launch xterm_4 -> slow
```

Likewise, the first command seems to execute but freezes for a second before moving forward. Say it is a `ls`, for instance. It prints a few words, freezes, then terminates correctly one second after that.

It also happens "once" until all `xterm` windows are closed:

```
Launch xterm_1 -> slow
Launch xterm_2 -> fast
ls in any_xterm -> slow
top in any_xterm -> fast
Close all xterm windows
Launch xterm_3 -> slow
Launch xterm_4 -> fast
ls in any_xterm -> slow
... and so on.
```

This does not affect all commands.

Affected commands:

- `ls`
- `top`
- `htop`
- `glances` (`htop`-like Python software)...
- `man`

Unaffected commands:

- `cat`
- `ping`
- `su` (unless symptom hidden by password typing time)
- `df`
- `du`
- `vi`

Also, it seems to be triggered but won't be noticed if the command returns almost immediately. For instance, `grep` is affected if and only if it yields at least one results. `ls my_almost_empty_directory` prints one line and returns fine. And subsequent `ls` works fine. More interestingly, `cd my_almost_empty_directory && ls && cd && ls` doesn't show any issue.

It is definitely a display issue as `grep` output is cut in the middle of a line, so `grep` processed the file and found a matching line but was interrupted while displaying it.

When running one affected command, any other affected command ran afterwards is instantaneous.

It happens for both my account and a guest account, so it does not seem related to my personal configuration. Also, if my first command is `su` and I change to root or guest, then the problem affects the first `ls` in the new session.

It happens for both linux 4.8 and 3.16.

Nothing like this happens with Mate terminal. There is no delay either when launching `ls` in another TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>,...)

Nothing relevant in `.xsession-errors` or root logs when it occurs.

It's been a few days now, although I don't remember exactly when it appeared and I can't correlate it with apt/aptitude update logs.

I have no idea how to find the root cause for this.

Comment: You say "root logs", but I'm not sure what you are referring to by that. Check your `dmesg`. I've had weird delays happen because of disk I/O problems; it's a good idea to rule that out (and the kernel will be screaming at you if that's the problem).

Comment: By root logs, I meant `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. I dispayed dmesg before and after the "freeze" and there was no new line.

Comment: I just noticed the problem disappeared. Maybe when I upgraded to Debian Stretch.